# What is the significance of extracted weight of Keras layer for doing forward pass without using Keras API

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, fpga

My intention is to know the kernel weight which has used during convolution and then do the forward pass on an image to classify. The work which is easy to do by using Keras API but it is a demand for my master's thesis as here I want to build a CNN model on FPGA only for testing/ classification.

Instead of using Keras API:

> 1/ I will write a plain code where I will give my preprocessed image as an input
>
> 2/ I will write convolution algorithm and give the extracted information of the Kernel to do the convolution
>
> 3/ I will write the algorithm for Flatten and
>
> 4/ By using Dense algorithm I want to **predict** the **class**

MY query is:

> 1/ What is the information actually is giving by **layer.get_weights()**? Is it giving us the kernel weight which will use for the convolution?
>
> 2/ If I want to do the classification with the help of extracted weight how can I approach?

The following is my model:(For simplicity I have just written a model with minimal layer)

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape,
                 activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    return model
model = cnn_model()
lr = 0.01
sgd = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer=sgd,
      metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the input image is grayscale and width, height is 80,80. 
I have trained my model using the following code:

```
def lr_schedule(epoch):
return lr * (0.1 ** int(epoch / 10))

batch_size = batch_size
epochs = nb_epoch
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
      #np.resize(img, (-1, <image shape>)
      callbacks= [LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule),
      ModelCheckpoint('path_to_save_model/model.h5', 
      save_best_only=True)])
```

I have extracted the layers weight by using:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import pandas as pd
weight_list=[]
for lay in model.layers:
    name=lay.name
    weight=lay.get_weights()
    print(name," layer weight is:\n\n",weight,"\n\n")
    weight_list.append(weight)


weight_array=[]
weight_array=np.array(weight_list)
print("weight_array's fist element is: \n\n",weight_array[0],"\n\n")
```

output of **weight_array=[0]** is

```
 [array([[[[ 0.3856341 ]],

    [[-0.35276324]],

    [[-0.51678646]]],


   [[[-0.62636113]],

    [[ 0.43428165]],

    [[-0.26765126]]],


   [[[ 0.461921  ]],

    [[-0.14468761]],

    [[-0.3061749 ]]]], dtype=float32), array([-0.1087065], dtype=float32)]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciatable.

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the information actually is giving by layer.get_weights()? Is it giving us the kernel weight which will use for the convolution?

For convolutional layers, `layer.get_weights()` returns [kernel, bias].

2) If I want to do the classification with the help of extracted weight how can I approach?

Replicate each stage of your network, the mathematics of which is well documented. Pay close attention to the exact operation being performed, for example 'convolution' in deep learning is not quite the same as in standard maths (no transform is applied). I suggest you pass a known input through the network and check that you get the same answers at every stage.

Comment: Will I try to start doing the convolution with the output of **weight_array=[0]**? I am assuming that if I can do the convolution with the kernel weight(index 0 of the output `layer.get_(weights)`) and then apply ReLU, Flatten, Dense and Softmax algorithm respectively classification will be done. I am confused whether I am thinking in the right way or not.

Comment: It sounds right. Don't forget to add the biases after the convolution. In your example you have a 3x3 convolution and then one bias value.

Comment: But how can I get a matrix of 3x3 to do the convolution? Is it the output of **weight_array=[0]**? It is a 4-dimensional array if I call it **weight_array=[0][0]** Is it right that I have to make it somehow 3x3 matrix or not? If YES then will I just simply add the bias value with the newly formed matrix?
Here, I am assuming `newly_formed_matrix= input_image_array  **conv** weight_array=[0][0] `

Comment: newly_formed_matrix= input_image_array **conv** weight_array=[0][0] + weight_array=[0][1]

Comment: By following [this](https://github.com/wiseodd/hipsternet/blob/master/hipsternet/im2col.py) I have tried to do the convolution where **out_shape:  (1, 3, 48, 50)** and **out_dim: 4**. Here, **out** is the output array after convolution. Train image is RGB. weight_array[0][0] shape is (3,3,3,1) and dim 4. Can you please provide me with any site where can I get more example of this explicit operation and also for Flatten and Dense?

Comment: Are you stuck with a particular problem? If so, please post a new question, as someone else might know better than me. Post a link here and I'll have a look when I can. Mark this question as answered if you are done with it, or edit it if you want someone else to jump in.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @jmsinusa . I have solved the issue of the weight file and successfully used the extracted weight to test CNN trained model to do classification. But, for now, I have done it only for 1 filter. Here, I am giving [the solution](https://github.com/atifkarim/Image-classification/blob/master/Predict_class_file_written_from_scratch_Numpy.ipynb) . Also, [the site](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-convolutional-neural-network-using-numpy-from-scratch-b30aac50e50a?fbclid=IwAR0UXh2F_5RcMMy34yZiNtipGUBYoJ0OfrzB33-UhC7AQK5lgv-7OYmX8vU) from where I have taken information.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explain the solution I have done and understood regarding my question. I am giving here [the solution](https://github.com/atifkarim/Image-classification/blob/master/Predict_class_file_written_from_scratch_Numpy.ipynb) that I have tried. Major information I have given from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-convolutional-neural-network-using-numpy-from-scratch-b30aac50e50a?fbclid=IwAR0UXh2F_5RcMMy34yZiNtipGUBYoJ0OfrzB33-UhC7AQK5lgv-7OYmX8vU).

In a model file **convolution kernel weight** , **convolution bias**, **Dense layer weight**, **Dense layer Bias** are stored. If anyone wants to write a Forward pass from scratch Numpy using Python or a function in C++ these kernels weights are important. Details information is given in the [Github link](https://github.com/atifkarim/Image-classification/blob/master/Predict_class_file_written_from_scratch_Numpy.ipynb)